# Having issues loading reset-client on Debian distro

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I'm trying to run an application that uses `rest-client` version `2.0.1`, however when I run the application I'm getting

```
/opt/whitewidow/lib/imports/constants_and_requires.rb:6:in require': cannot load such file -- rest-client (LoadError) from /opt/whitewidow/lib/imports/constants_and_requires.rb:6:in<top (required)>'
from whitewidow.rb:2:in require_relative' from whitewidow.rb:2:in
```

What I've tried to do is edit the code to use `restclient` instead of `rest-client` but that just throws the same issue, I tried install a version lower with `gem install rest-client -v 2.0` I get the same error.

Now here's the weird part, the application runs on Windows 7, but not on a Debian distro, is there a trick to running rest-client on a Linux distro? here's all the requirements:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rest-client'
require 'timeout'
require 'uri'
require 'fileutils'
require 'yaml'
require 'date'
require 'optparse'
require 'tempfile'
require 'socket'
require 'net/http'
require 'ipaddr'
require 'csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bundled the application on windows it will not execute properly. This is because it compiles with the windows binaries.

Try deleting your Gemfile.lock and rebundling.

Comment: same issue, throws the same error, would updating bundler do anything?